# Evaluate $\int\frac{1}{\sec x\tan^2 x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int\frac{1}{\sec x\tan^2 x}dx$$

I first thought of using the property $\int\sec^2 x = \tan x$ but figured it's no use.

How would I go by solving this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the function with $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions, giving you $$\int\frac{\cos^3 x}{\sin^2 x}dx,$$
then rewrite it as $$\int \frac{(1-\sin^2x) \cos x}{\sin^2 x} dx$$

Now, make a substitution. It should be pretty obvious which one.

Answer (score 2):

$\int\dfrac{(1 - \sin^2 x)\cos x}{\sin^2 x}dx = \int\dfrac{(1 - \sin^2 x}{\sin^2 x}d(\sin x) = \int\biggl(\dfrac{1}{u^2} - 1\biggr)du = -\dfrac{1}{u} - u \quad \Rightarrow$
$\int \dfrac{\cos^3x}{\sin^2x}dx = -\dfrac{1}{\sin x} - \sin x + C$